# Gitlab extra http:// in cloning links

Tags: git, gitlab

I've migrated my gitlab installation from server A (gitlab 6.1 rc1) to server B (gitlab 6.8).

Now I noticed that the links to clone projects contain an extra `http://` so the links look like `git@http:// my.git.serverB:myproject.git` while it should be `git@my.git.serverB:myproject.git`.

This is currently for all the projects on the git server (41).
Does anyone knows how (or where) to fix this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely it is in the `gitlab.yml` file, and on more recent installs of Gitlab, this is found here

`/var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-rails/etc/gitlab.yml`

What you are looking for is the FQDN entry, near the top, and you probably have an extra `http://` in there.

Look for the

`host: ictest.no-ip.biz`

line, and see if it has `http://` in it.

Then you would need to update that, and then run the gitlab reconfigure, possibly using `sudo`...

`sudo gitlab-ctl reconfigure`

There are other posts here that suggest that you have to update your hostname entry in multiple places, so I would check those too.